# How to switch from ubuntu to window 7?

Tags: windows-7, application-switcher, switch-user

I want to ask. I'm using window 7 and I'm trying to install ubuntu. So my computer is running 2 operating system. My problem right now is I can't switch back to windows and I don't have the option to go back to windows. What should I do? please help me

Comment: Which method have  you used to install ubuntu

Comment: Hi you should be able to swap between the linux and windows partition at boot if you installed ubuntu correctly as a secondary OS.

Do you remember what kind of installation you chose?

Can you post here the output of the command `sudo fdisk -l` please?

Answer (score 0):

**Questions you should be asking:** 
- Does the partition table show Windows7 still exists?
- What is the boot order BIOS references?

**Additional Information that would be useful**
- What kind of computer are you using?
  - Have you looked into the key combination to access the boot menu for your specific computer?

**Assuming all is True**
- The problem, if Windows still exists, is the first bootloader BIOS finds in its boot order schema is calling Grub.

**Potential Fix** *<sub>Based on the latter</sub>*
- Google the key combination (usually `ESC`, `F8` or `F10`) for your specific computer to access the boot menu at the initial BIOS splash page.
- Once you are at the boot menu you can select the Windows partition and it will boot directly to it.